# Starcraft 2 Hotkeys

Tags: starcraft-2

So I know this is a common question asked by new players to Starcraft 2;
    I was wondering how to add a unit or structure to a group within the hotkey?

Furthermore:

1. How can you select all hatcheries as zerg (I assume it is the same as above)?
2. Is there a way to select all attacking units in an area as I find overlords tend to hover over my army?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How can you select all hatcheries as zerg (I assume it is the same as above)?**

- Add each hatchery that you are building to any group that you like. Usually I have all of them assigned to '5'. When I need to build something - just press '5', 's', and then hot-key for required unit. Also I have all queens assigned to 4, at least 1 queen per hatchery, and I do 'larva-spawn' by pressing '4', and then for each hatchery press 'v' and then click on minimap on place where hatchery is located. In this way you will also spawn larvas without moving screen to each hatchery.

**Is there a way to select all attacking units in an area as I find overlords tend to hover over my army?**

- usually once in a while you need ctrl-click on overlords (keep 'Ctrl' button and click on any overlord) to select all of them on screen and send them to some place that is not a rally point.
  If you are in hurry - round box everything, do required order, and AFTER that ctrl-click on overlords and send them away.
- optionally, if you have only few units types on the screen you can ctrl-click one type, then keep additionally pressed 'Shift' button select another type of units...

P.S. Also is good to have you rally point location on any Fx hot key (to be able quickly navigate to this place).

Comment: thanks, but could you explain how i would add a unit to a group? for example a Lair hatchery to a group of hatcheries on key 5?

Comment: Select both by holding down 'shift' and clicking them. Then press 'ctrl+5'. If you want to add another one later, press 'alt+5', hold shift, select the new one and press 'ctrl+5'. You can shift click as many as you like in one batch. You could even group 5 zerglings, an overlord, a pool all together in one rather pointless group using this method - just by shift clicking each and assigning a group.

Comment: Two add any unit/building into existing group you have 2 options: 1) select unit, and then press shift+# (keep pressed Shift, and press required group number); 2) press required group number (to select group), shift-click on required unit/building (to add unit into group), press Ctrl+# to store new group.

Answer (score 1):

To **create** group 1, select units/structures and press CTRL+1.
If group 1 already exists, it is replaced by the new one.

To **add** units/structures to group 1, select new units/structures and press SHIFT+1.
If group 1 does not exist, it is created.

For example, I personnaly bind all my nexuses to group 4. At the beginning of the game, I select my nexus and press SHIFT+4.
Later, for each new nexus created, I select them while they're building, and press SHIFT+4.

Answer (score 0):

Short answers are:

1. there is not such key. You should use control group for this
2. I don't quite understand a question. If you bind your overlords to control group accidentally and want to remove them: `ctrl+shift+click` at any overlord in group info at the bottom of the screen and rebind a group.